# Searching for a list of string in a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a list of names, and a data.frame with many different columns. How can I retrieve rows in the data frame that their row.name is one of the names in my list?

For example if the row.names in my data frame has many rows, including `TC09001536.hg.1` ,  `TC03002852.hg.1` , and `TC18000664.hg.1` names, which are saved in list called `Top.list`.
Assuming my data frame is called df then I tried:

```
test <- df[grep(Top.list, df$cluster_id),]
```

to look within `cluster_id` column and if matches the names in my list then give me whole rows.

Comment: I don't really understand your question, but if you're trying to get `row.names` of `df`in `top.list`, then you would do `df[row.names(df) %in% top.list,]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
test <- df[unlist(lapply(Top.list, function(x) grep(x, df$cluster_id, fixed = TRUE))),]
```

The `lapply(Top.list, function(x) grep(x, df$cluster_id, fixed = TRUE))` part generates a list with vectors of matching row numbers for each of your words, the `unlist` combines the vectors to one vector, from which your dataframe will be subsetted.

Comment: Thanks a lot Leo. Would this also work if the strings in Top.list were row.names of another data.frame, for example row.names(df2) instead of Top.list in your code ?

Comment: The code would work with every vector/list of corresponding strings I can think of. Would you want to search for rownames of one dataframe in the rownames of the other, or again in the variable `cluster_id`?

Comment: yes, rownames of one dataframe in the variable cluster_id.

Comment: Yep, that should work exactly as above. Just put in `rownames(df)` instead of `Top.list`.

Comment: I am trying to look up strings in one column of data.frame1 in a variable "external_gene from data.frame2, and extract all rows from data.frame 2 where there are matches.
and since I have 52 columns in my data.frame, I want to perform similar search for the renaming column in the variable "external_gene from data.frame2.
Couldn't get the grep function doing the job.How should I do it?
Thanks a lot in avance.

Comment: So you have the strings you want to search for in the variable `external_gene`, like `Top.list` in your previous problem, and want to search for these strings in multiple columns?

Comment: Actually, variable external_gene is similar to variable cluster_id in previous problem and I want to search strings in other 52 columns in data.frame2$external_gene, but one column at the time, because I need to know which column the output is referring to.

Comment: Well, you would need to nest your `apply`-calls on the `grep`-call. Going from the example in my answer above, you would generate a new subset for each of your 52 columns, all put together in a list: `test <- lapply(df[1:52], function(x) subset(df, unlist(lapply(x, function(y) grepl(y, df$external_gene, fixed = TRUE)))))`. This should give you a list of 52 subsets, one for each of your columns. Notice I used `grepl` instead of `grep` to output a logical vector, which is needed for using `subset`. You need to replace the `[1:52]` with the real positions of your columns.

Comment: It might also be easier to first compile a list of your unique strings with `New.List <- lapply(df[1:52], unique)` and then use `New.List` instead of `df[1:52]` in the call above.

Comment: test <- lapply(GeneSig[2:51], function(x) subset(GeneSig, unlist(lapply(x, function(y) grepl(y, genes$external_gene, fixed = TRUE)))))
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 110.5 Mb. 

Also tried for 1 col ;
test <- lapply(GeneSig[2], function(x) subset(GeneSig, unlist(lapply(x, function(y) grepl(y, genes$external_gene, fixed = TRUE)))))

Error: cannot allocate vector of size 428 Kb.

Insufficient memory?

Comment: Yep, that seems to be the problem. Try the approach with making a list first (my last comment above), maybe that will help. Else you would need to clear a part of your memory by other means. How many rows do you have in your data?

Comment: I tried
New.List <- lapply(GeneSig[2:51], unique)
the output seems correct, and then
test <- lapply(New.List, function(x) subset(New.List, unlist(lapply(x, function(y) grepl(y, genes$external_gene, fixed = TRUE)))))
output is NA values.
dim(genes) says 54838 rows

Comment: Your line of code is wrong. It should be `subset(genes, ...`, not `subset(New.List, ...`

Comment: My bad! changed it but still the output list has all the col names of genes df but all are filled NAs.
I might be doing something wrong, but for example when I `x <- intersect(GeneSig[,2], genes$external_gene)` I get couple of matching string but the I need info in whole row for each of those finding.

Comment: Hm, I could only test it on some of my own data with a rather simple approach, but for me it worked. I would advise you to try it with the first two columns (`New.List <- lapply(GeneSig[2:3], unique)`) and then check if the Output of `New.List` seems reasonable. Afterwards, do the subsetting and figure out where the error occurs.